# Java Swing Frame navigate to another Frame

Tags: java, oop

This is my main class.

```
package pomsystem;

public class POMSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ItemList();
    }
}
```

This is the second class frame that I want to navigate.

```
package pomsystem;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class UI extends JFrame{
    TextField txtID, txtItem, txtStock, txtSupplierID;
    Label lblID, lblItem, lblStock, lblSupplierID;
    Button btnSearch, btnClear, btnBack;
}

public class ItemList extends UI {
    private String ID;
    private int Stock;

    public ItemList(String ID, int Stock) {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLocation(380, 120);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Item Entry");
        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }
}
```

It shown me a error with Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types, I know the error is from the parameters of second frame.
Is that any approach to solve the problem.
I'm new to Java OOP sorry.

Comment: Since you declared a custom constructor, the default constructor `ItemList()` doesn't exist, you have to call your custom one : `ItemList(String ID, int Stock)` .

Comment: Can you briefly explain how I could call another constructor with working parameters.

Comment: You just have to pass a `String` and an `int` parameters, e.g : `new ItemList("myID", 1000);` .

Comment: It working mate, thank you much. However what if I want to pass multiple data like ID001, ID002. How can I modify the code?

Comment: Please add details about how your application will be supposed to work.

Comment: Since this project will connect with an external text file(.txt) which stored the ItemID and stock, so that I can use a class method to read data from the text file and pass it to another frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a custom constructor:

```
    public ItemList(String ID, int Stock){


    setSize(600,400);
    setLocation(380,120);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Item Entry");
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);}
```

overwriting the standard empty Java Object constructor, which is:

```
public ItemList(){}
```

Just add the constructor without arguments again in your code as an alternative constructor:

```
 public ItemList(){

    setSize(600,400);
    setLocation(380,120);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Item Entry");
    setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);}
```

}

Otherwise you could also call your custom constructor with values:

```
new ItemList("example", 0);
```

Comment: It builds successfully but no more frame pops up when I run the project.

Comment: You of course have to add the code, you want to execute in the empty constructor. I assume it's the code, I have just added to it.